# Technical term needed: Per default secured / blacklist vs whitelist

Tags: terminology, whitelist, blacklist

I'm currently working on a homework and missing a technical term / known best practice to describe what I have learned or what I feel that is better. It is about a publish / subscribe architecture, where channels are per default open and unauthenticated, and you have to configure security explicitly (kind of *blacklisting instead of whitelisting*). Imho it would be more secure to have channels be authenticated / secured per default and open them on configuration, so you can't forget it if you need authentication.

I hope I could explain to you in what direction I'm thinking. I really need a technical term for this, but have no idea currently. Blacklist vs. Whitelist is the closest thing I came up with, but this is not a general pattern, is it? And it is not exactly what I mean..

Anyone may help? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the term [secure by default](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_by_default) captures what you are looking for:

> In a network operating system, this typically means first and foremost
>   that there are no listening INET(6) domain sockets after installation.
>   That is, no open network ports. This can be checked on the local
>   machine with a tool such as netstat, and remotely with a port scanner
>   such as nmap. As a general rule, a secure network, is only as secure
>   as the least secure node in the entire network.

Comment: Thank a lot, didn't know there was a best practice called like this, just had a "feeling" for it!